# MVC4 model binding with two complex models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have an action on my controller that takes two parameters that should be captured when a form is posted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, FormAction action)
```

The idea is that the model data should be captured in `MyModel` and the button that the user pressed should be captured in `FormAction`:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}

public class FormAction
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model TestApp.Models.MyModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyValue)

             <input type="submit" value="OK" name="command" />
             <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="command" />
        }

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I add another string parameter to the action called 'command' then the value of the button comes through but it doesn't get bound to the `Command` property on the `FormAction` parameter - the parameter is always null.

If I add a `Command` property to `MyModel` then the button value does come through.

Is there something in MVC model binding that prevents more than one complex model to be bound in one action method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got to the bottom of this and the reason it wasn't working was simply because the parameter was named **action**.  This is pretty much the equivalent of a keyword in MVC and it is used by the MVC framework to identify the action to be executed.

Changing the parameter name to something else means that the `Command` property comes through as expected!

Answer (score 0):

The metter is that `Html.BeginForm` sends only model from top statenent: `@model TestApp.Models.MyModel`. If I clearly understand what you whant to do, the better solution will be to create ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public MyModel myModel {get; set;}
public FormAction formAction {get; set;}
}
```

Change View as follows:

```
@model TestApp.Models.ViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.myModel.MyValue)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.formAction.Command)

             <input type="submit" value="OK" name="command" />
             <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="command" />
        }

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And change your Action to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
```

Comment: I've not marked this up because the premise is not correct but it is the exact workaround that I ended up implementing before I worked out what the real issue was.